# limit random complex number to a given range

Tags: matlab, octave, complex-numbers

I can get the real part of a random number to stay withing a given range but the complex part of the number doesn't stay within the range I set. **see matlab / octave code below.**

```
xmin=-.5
xmax=1
n=3
x=xmin+rand(1,n)*(xmax-xmin)+(rand(1,n)-(xmax-xmin))*1i
x=x(:)
```

**The real part works but the complex part isn't limited to -0.5 to 1**

```
0.2419028288441536 - 0.6579427654754871i
0.2712527227134944 - 1.451964497492678i
0.3245051849394858 - 1.107556052779179i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two mistakes:

```
 x=xmin+rand(1,n)*(xmax-xmin)+(xmin + rand(1,n)*(xmax-xmin))*1i
```

You should add `xmin` to the sum and change `-` to `*` in the second part.

Answer (score 1):

I've added some spaces to your code so the difference more obvious:

```
x =  xmin+rand(1,n)*(xmax-xmin)  +  (  rand(1,n)-(xmax-xmin)  )*1i
     ^^^ correct                       ^^^ not correct: missing `xmin+`
                                           (and as OmG noted, also a `-` instead of a `*`)
```

---

One good way to reduce the number of bugs is by avoiding code duplication. You could for example write:

```
rand_sequence = @(m,xmin,xmax) xmin+rand(1,n)*(xmax-xmin);
x = rand_sequence(n,xmin,xmax) + 1i*rand_sequence(n,xmin,xmax)
```

(This looks like more code, but the more complicated code logic is not duplicated.)

Or like this:

```
x = xmin + (rand(1,n)+1i*rand(1,n)) * (xmax-xmin);
```

Comment: Per OmG's answer, also a typo with `-(xmax-min)` which should be `*(xmax-xmin)`

Comment: @Wolfie: True, I hadn't noticed that. I didn't mean to spend this much time on a typo. :)